# Hide section header "Prototype Cells" in Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

I have Googled and Googled, but no luck... I am trying to hide the "Prototype Cells" section header that appears when you add a UITableView to a UIView using Storyboard.

[image]

It is frustrating, because it is hard to size the Cells to the screen, as that disappears when you run the program. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! Thanks and I am sorry if this is a simple question, I am new to this.

Comment: That doesn't show up when you run the app. I don't think there's anyway to hide it on your storyboard.

Comment: If you're able to use static cells the header will go away.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I can't use static because I want to have a view above my TableView so I have to use a UIViewController, and not a UITableViewController. Am I incorrect?

Comment: No, you can do this with a UITableView. I have done this a few times. Try to search for 'floating view in table view'. There was also a WWDC session where this was shown.

Comment: Do you have a link to the WWDC session? I can't seem to find it anywhere. Thank you!

Comment: @dasdom:  While you *can* do that with a UITableView, you *can't* do it with a *static* UITableView, because it is required to be in a UITableViewController (instead of a UIViewController).  This makes the table view automatically resize to the full size of the UITableViewController.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually the auto generated section header that appears at the beginning of the section.
In XCode 5 when you have UITableView, click on the Table View Section -Header Title.Click on the attributes segment.

[image]

[image]

I you delete the text in Header "Header Title", this should remove the section header.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to change the *Prototype Cells* number in *Attributes Inspector*. In the example below I have used a UITableView inside a UIView. But like the other comments say, it won't really affect your code. This is just to hide it in the storyboard.

[image: Prototype Cells : 5]
[image: Prototype Cells : 0]

Comment: The "Prototype Cells" is still there in the second picture. Are the pictures supposed to be reversed? Thanks for the response!

Comment: Hi, I was just highlighting the difference between the two pictures, not necessarily in order. Just make sure that the "Prototype Cells" count is set to 0 in the second row (of Attributes Inspector) like in the left hand side of the screen capture.